# How to use octave for data from c++ in c++

Tags: c++, octave

I have a c++ file which reads in some data as Float_t-arrays. On these I want to apply some octave functions (e.q. fft). How do I do that? Do I firstly have to convert Float_t into an octave variable? 
Thanks!

I have:

```
int main()
{
Float values[10];

//do magic with octave, e.q. fft

// store the data back into values or keep them (?)
}
```

I know I can do the following:

```
int main()
{
Float values[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

Matrix a_matrix = Matrix (2,2);
a_matrix(0,0) = values[0];

cout << "Matrix: " << a_matrix << endl;
}
```

How do I do this with fft on the values-array?

Comment: What have you tried doing? Show your code and explain what the issues are

Comment: @UnholySheep At first thanks! I edited the question a bit, hope it is now understandable?

Comment: @Ben this might help: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/External-Code-Interface.html#External-Code-Interface (specifically the oct and standalone sections)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thank you! Unfortunately I already know that. But I don't get it how to use e.g. fft. In the documentary itself there is only given:

fft(x)

Comment: If you want to calculate fft and ifft in C++ you should use http://fftw.org/ directly. GNU Octave also uses fftw

Comment: @Andy Thanks, good to know! Actually I wanted to compare several functions out of octave with each other. fft is just the first - and it took me several days to get octave running embedded in my code :)

Comment: @Ben: where can I find your full code?

Comment: @Andy The full code? I uploaded it on https://github.com/DeLaRiva/Code/blob/master/Filter.cpp The part where I want to use an octave function is in line 303.

Comment: @Ben No, I ask for the whole project source tree. Since you want to use Octave function (and link against liboctave) you're project also has to be GPL. See for example here: http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#I_wrote_a_program_that_links_with_Octave_libraries_and_I_don.27t_want_to_release_it_under_the_terms_of_the_GPL._Will_you_change_the_license_of_the_Octave_libraries_for_me.3F

Comment: @Andy Sorry, I guess I don't know what a source tree is. The uploaded file is the complete program. Do you mean the makefile is missing? What's meant by GPL? I have no problem to release it (didn't I do that already on github?).

Comment: @Ben you want to generate a octave source code from C and then run octave?

Comment: @Andy "Since you want to use Octave function (and link against liboctave) your project also has to be GPL" <-- this sounds like the kind of conversation that would have been had an infinite number of times already, but this sounds very weird to me. It's the first I've heard it. Surely the only strict GPL requirement in such a project should have been that the GPL libraries used / modified are identified and licenced as such. "You linked to our libraries therefore all your work belong to us" sounds a bit like a freedom-fighter going on a bit of an overzealous power-trip.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou This has nothing to do with "your work belong to us" but if you link against a GPL lib you have to grant others the same right so see and use your code. Have you never heard of the difference GPL<->LGPL?

Comment: @Andy I had, but admittedly I'd forgotten the specifics here :p. You're right, I guess the meaning I intended and the way I should be phrasing it is that the LGPL would make more sense here (but I don't want to start that discussion, I'm sure this has been covered many times).

Comment: Ok,..  I'm confused now...do I have to consider anything related to your discussion? Shall I do something with my code respectively publish it somewhere/is there a plattform of every code ever written with octave? Would be nice in such a way I would probably have a lot of examples :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pantxo gave you the correct [answer on the help mailinglist](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/how-to-use-fft-in-c-tp4683590p4683592.html). I add it here for completeness:

> Since fft and related function are builtin you probably can include
>    and call Ffft directly (without the
>   need for feval) in your code. As an example the following code can be
>   compiled with mkocfile and works for me:

```
//////////////////////////testfft.cc//////////////////
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/builtin-defun-decls.h>

DEFUN_DLD(testfft, args, nargout, "\
testfft\n\
")
{
  octave_value_list retval;
  int nargin = args.length ();

  retval = Ffft (args);
  return retval;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Compile and test in Octave:

mkoctfile testfft.cc
x = 1:10;
all (testfft (x) == fft (x))
```

**EDIT**

Since you have problems adapting this as standalone, I'll create another example:

```
// file main.cc
// compile and link with mkoctfile --link-stand-alone main.cc -o bentest
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/builtin-defun-decls.h>

int main ()
{
  Matrix a = Matrix (1,4);
  for (int k = 0; k < a.columns (); ++k)
    a(0, k) = k % 2;

  std::cout << "in:" << a << std::endl;

  octave_value_list in;
  in(0) = a;

  octave_value_list out = Ffft (in, 1);
  ComplexMatrix o = out(0).complex_matrix_value ();
  std::cout << "out:" << o << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which outputs.

```
in: 0 1 0 1

out: (2,0) (0,0) (-2,0) (0,0)
```

Comment: This doesn't sound right. This seems to produce an octfile for use within Octave. The questions seems to ask for a c++ standalone that makes use of octave libraries instead.

Comment: @Tasos: of course only the part inside "{ }" The key here is to use `Ffft ()`. It doesn't matter if you call it in an oct file or a standalone application

Comment: @Andy thanks! Sorry for cross-posting. I was a little bit scared because of so many downvotes. On cs.ex 3 of 4 of my posts got blocked with less down votes. So I thought before this happens again here I go to the natural plattform.
But anyhow, I'll follow the discussion now there.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works also on my machine, can now implement it according to my stuff. Thanks a lot!